# React native - useEffect not triggering upon rendering of the component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I am trying to create what should be a simple countdown component in react native, using redux for state management. I'm doing it with useEffect, and there's a button to cancel the countdown.

The app bundles and the component loads. The counter starts at 7, it renders and one second later it goes down to 6 and it renders. However it stops there. It won't go past 6.

I'm hoping to get help figuring out why.

```
export const Countdown: FC<CountdownProps> = ({navigation}) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const currentCount = useAppSelector((state) => state.countdown.currentCount)
    const isCountdownFinished = useAppSelector((state) => state.countdown.isCountdownFinished)
    const isCountdownCancelled = useAppSelector((state) => state.countdown.isCountdownCancelled)
 
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(resetCurrentCount())
        dispatch(setIsCountdownCancelled(false))
        dispatch(setIsCountdownFinished(false))

    }, [])

   // Logic for the countdown. Checks if the countdown is finished or cancelled. 
    // If it's neither, it will dispatch the next count after 1 second has passed.
    useEffect(() => {
        if(isCountdownFinished) {
            handleFinishedCountdown()
        } else if(isCountdownCancelled){
            handleCancelledCountdown()
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch(reduceCurrentCountByOne())
            }, 1000);       
        }
    }, [dispatch])  
    
    const handleCancelledCountdown = () => {
 // stuff
    }

    const handleFinishedCountdown = () => {
// stuff
    }

    const handleCancelButtonPress = () => {
        dispatch(setIsCountdownCancelled(true))
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{currentCount}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCancelButtonPress}>
                <Text>CANCEL!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I have tried changing the countdown initial values, wrapping the setTimeOut call inside a requestAnimationFrame call, changing my TouchableOpacity to Pressable since TO seems to be buggy. Can't seem to get the countdown to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only issue I see with the `useEffect` hook code usage is missing `isCountdownFinished`, `handleFinishedCountdown`, `isCountdownCancelled`, and `handleCancelledCountdown` dependencies. These should all be added to the dependency array.

```js
// Logic for the countdown. Checks if the countdown is finished or cancelled. 
// If it's neither, it will dispatch the next count after 1 second has passed.
useEffect(() => {
  if (isCountdownFinished) {
    handleFinishedCountdown();
  } else if (isCountdownCancelled) {
    handleCancelledCountdown();
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(reduceCurrentCountByOne());
    }, 1000);       
  }
}, [
  dispatch,
  handleCancelledCountdown,
  handleFinishedCountdown,
  isCountdownCancelled,
  isCountdownFinished
]);
```

An alternative might be to use an interval and import the `useStore` hook so you can access the current state in the closed-over callback.

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector, useStore } from 'react-redux';

...

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const store = useStore();

useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    const {
      isCountdownFinished,
      isCountdownCancelled
    } = state.countdown;

    if (isCountdownFinished) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      handleFinishedCountdown();
    } else if (isCountdownCancelled) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      handleCancelledCountdown();
    } else {
      dispatch(reduceCurrentCountByOne());
    }
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };
}, [store]);
```